# Angular 2 reload page on link with new parameters

Tags: angular

my page describes student's details, in addition I've component on my page like combo with other students' list , when I select other student from my list and click on it (it's a link I'm using href) I want the same page to be shown but with details of student that I clicked on it.

```
<a *ngIf="student?.studentId!=studentId" [routerLink]="['/studentDetailsContainer',student?.Branch,student?.studentId]"/>
```

This is my component code:

```js
    @Component({
    selector: 'studentDetails',
    templateUrl: './app/student/student.details.html',  
})
export class StudentDetailsComponent extends TooltipComponent implements OnInit {
    public students: Student[];
    public student: Student;    
    public studentId: number;
    private sub: any;
    private branch: number;
    private AdditionsArr: Student[];
    public AllStudents: Student[]
    constructor(private studentDetailservice: StudentService, private route: ActivatedRoute, tooltipService: TooltipService) {
        super(tooltipService);
    }
    getStudent() {
        this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.studentId = +params['studentId'];
            this.branch = +params['branch'];
        });   
        this.studentDetailservice.getStudent(this.branch, this.studentId).subscribe(data => {
            this.students = data;
            this.studentDetails = this.students[0];
            this.AdditionsArr = this.studentDetails.AdditionsArr;           
        }, err => {
        });
    }
    getStudents() {
        this.studentDetailservice.getStudents().subscribe(data => {
            this.AllStudents = data;
        })
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
       
        this. getStudents();
        this.getStudent();
   
    }
}
```

The function that should bring me selected student details is getStudent(). When I debug I get only this.sub and fill params, after that I do not come back to get details from service....

The result that I get now is that URL is changed and my list is changed (the student that I linked on is not in the list as wanted.) But the page is with the same student details as before.... I think I need some event to reload my page... Someone can help me? Thank you.

Comment: please, post the code about your route params subscription, are you using the `route.snapshot` property? If I do understand what you are doing, you are trying to use the same component, right ?

Comment: yes' I want to show the same component', I want to navigate to the same page but with new student Id. I'm not using route.snapshot , but I understand that even if I use it I need to insert it in ngOnInit() function, but the problem is that the page is not reloading and I don't reach this function by clicking my link....I need to reload the page somehow...

Comment: Once again... Please, provide your component code.